# ArrayBlockingQueue has two condition: notFull and notEmpty. How to understand these two condition? It is a kind of lock splitting?

Tags: java, locking, blockingqueue

If it is a strategy of lock splitting, I see that the mutable manipulation: put is guaranteed by lock.

Comment: Where do you see those two conditions? In what context? Your question is not clear.

Comment: They are not locks, but signals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're talking about the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.java)

They are not locks, but signals (`Conditions`).

One which threads putting values will wait on for space to be available to put, that's `notFull`.

One which threads reading values will wait on for an item to be added, that's `notEmpty`.

Comment: Thanks! I see the implementation of Condition in AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.

Comment: Can I see the Condition as a kind of Semaphore?

Comment: Thanks! You are very nice.